# Blazor problem deploying to Windows server 2012 R2 -- running Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, blazor, iis-8

I have a simple Blazor application (based on the example file in visual studio) which works on my computer running Visual Studio 2019, when I test it using "IIS Express" emulator. However, I cannot get it to work by deploying on a Windows server 2012 R2 using IIS 8.5.

On the server side, I have installed the latest .NET Core 3.1 hosting bundle, enabled IIS web server, set my application pool to "no managed code", and added a new website using site name and the proper physical path.

In Visual Studio I am using the "file system" profile with target runtime "portable", which I transfer to the hosting folder in my server:

[image]

However when I browse the website I am getting the message

> This page can’t be displayed

Answer (score 1):

Update -- After double checking I am running .NET core hosting bundle hosting bundle ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.3 and SDK 3.1.201 on my machine I was able to get this working..

Comment: SDK shouldn't be needed.